# Parsing string to integer in BeanShell Sampler in JMeter

Tags: java, string, integer, jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to parse a string into integer in JMeter but failed due to following error. If I try to print the strings returned by vars.get, they look good.

```
2014/06/28 00:08:52 WARN  - jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``if (ResponseCode != null && ResponseCode.equals ("200") == false ) {  int i = In . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt
```

Following is my code

```
if (ResponseCode != null && ResponseCode.equals ("200") == false )
{
    int i = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("currentPMCount"));
    int j = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("pmViolationMaxCount"));
    if( i > j ){
        log.warn("PM count on server is greater than max allowed count.");
        }

        log.warn( "The return code is " + ResponseCode); // this goes to the JMeter log file
} 
else 
{
    Failure=true ;
    FailureMessage = "The response data size was not as expected" ;   
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code looks good however it can be a problem with `currentPMCount` and/or `pmViolationMaxCount` variables.

If they really look good and look like Integers and don't exceed maximum/minimum values of Integer you can try the following:

1. Make sure that there are no "space" characters around number value as leading or trailing space will cause conversion failure. Perhaps invoking `trim()` method on variable can help:

   ```
   int i = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("currentPMCount").trim());
   ```
2. If you store your script into a file and then provide path to the file in Beanshell Assertion you'll get "problematic" line number
3. My favourite: surround your code into try/catch block as follows:

   ```
   try{
       //your code here
   }
   catch (Exception ex){
       log.warn("Error in my script", ex);
       throw ex; // elsewise JMeter will "swallow" the above exception
   }
   ```

This way you'll get more informative stacktrace instead of lousy `Error invoking bsh method`message which tells nothing.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more tips and tricks.

Comment: currentPMCount was null because of a wrong regular expression but the error message thrown was very vague to realize. Thanks for the help.